# SAS- How Code an array from previous set of variables

Tags: sas

I need to create a new variable in which is comprised of a list of other variables found in my dataset.

```
HAD1 (1=yes 2=no 9=unknown),
HAF10 (1=yes 2=no 9=unknown), 
HAC1C (1=yes 2=no 9=unknown), 
and HAC1D (1=yes 2=no 9=unknown)
```

to add up the number of health conditions an individual has. I also want to set all 9 to equal "."
My new variable will be named CC4

```
CC4 = 

(0=no conditions, 
1=one condition, 
2=two conditions, 
3=three conditions, 
4=four conditions, 
.=any condition appears missing)
```

How do I code it in the correct way and add it to my dataset?

I only wrote this:

```
data dataset;
set dataset;

*use arrays to create clean, re-coded versions of variables;
array code1 [4] HAD1 HAF10 HAC1C HAC1D;
array code2 [4] diabetes hattack hfailure stroke;
do new= 1 to 4;

if code1 [new] = 1 then code2 [new] = 1;
*keep all 1's as 1's;

else if code1 [new] = 2 then code2 [new] = 2;
*keep all 2's as 2's;

else if code1 [new] = 9 then code2 [new] = .;
*make all 9's into .'s;

end;
drop new;

*create summation variable;
cc4=HAD1+HAF10+HAC1C+HAC1D;
```

Comment: Do you really want to recode the variables or do you really only need to generate the count ?

Comment: @Tom I would use the new cc4 variable in a table to get description statistics like frequency and p value

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to recode to count.

You can take advantage of SAS evaluating boolean expressions to 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE.

```
data want;
  set have;
  cc4 = (HAD1=1)+(HAF10=1)+(HAC1C=1)+(HAC1D=1);
run;
```

PS Do not overwrite your input data by using the same dataset name in the DATA and SET statements.  It will make it hard to correct coding mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want new names for the original code variables, use `RENAME`
If you want new names and the original code variables, probably shouldn't

If you only want the cc4 result, you can use the fact of a single digit code for meaning to compute your condition count when all conditions assert a yes/no state.

Example:

```
data have;
  do code1 = 1,2,9;
  do code2 = 1,2,9;
  do code3 = 1,2,9;
  do code4 = 1,2,9;
    output;
  end;end;end;end;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  codes = cats(code1,code2,code3,code4);
  drop codes;

  cc4 = ifn(index(codes,'9'),.,count(codes,'1'));
run;
```

In your case replace `code1,code2,code3,code4` with `HAD1,HAF10,HAC1C,HAC1D`